# Recycler View Item Decoration does not get focus and Talkback does not announce it

Tags: android-recyclerview, talkback, accessibility

I am using Custom Recycler View Item Decoration. When I switch on TalkBack, all the Recycler View items get focus and Talkback announces it but View Item decorators do not get focus and Talkback does not announce them.

What I am missing ? How can I gain focus for the same?

[image]

In the above, when I switch ON Talkback, "Updated January 2020" and "Updated 2019" does not get focus and talkback do not announce them.

Comment: hey, did you able to resolve this, I am having similar issue

Comment: Hey, i am facing the same issue, any update here?

Comment: Not able to solve it. This seems to be the issue in 3rd part library we use.

Comment: Still no update? I'm having the same issues!